# How to load CSV file from GCS in read only mode

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

```
file_name = "r1.csv"
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('upload-testing')
blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)
blob.download_to_filename("csv_file")
```

Want to Open r1.csv file in read only Mode.
Getting this Error

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as file_obj:
Error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'csv_file'
```

so the function download_to_filename open files in `wb` mode  is there any way threw which i can open r1.csv in read-only mode

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? Are you trying to modify the GCS file directly?

Comment: No i want to create a  single .xlxs file  from multiple csv files(first step is open csv file from GCS in cloud function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in previous answer you need to use the `r` mode, however you don't need to specify that since that's the default mode.

In order to be able to read the file itself, you'll need to download it first, then read its content and treat the data as you want. The following example downloads the GCS file to a temporary folder, opens that downloaded object and gets all its data:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("<BUCKET_NAME>")
blob = bucket.blob("<CSV_NAME>")
blob.download_to_filename("/tmp/test.csv")
with open("/tmp/test.csv") as file:
    data = file.read()
    <TREAT_DATA_AS_YOU_WISH>
```

This example is thought to run inside GAE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a read only file you should use `'r'` mode, `'wb'` means `write binary`:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
```

Comment: i know this, i was asking  how i can open r1.csv file in read only mode from cloud storage.

Comment: what do you mean? you cannot modify the file on GCS directly, you have to download it to local machine and then open it.

Comment: am not modifying it ,i just wanted to open it in read-only mode

Comment: you cannot open directly from GCS, it has to be downloaded first

Comment: am doing the same check the code written above, but this function download_to_filename is throwing error.

Comment: where are you trying to save the file? it seems your filesystem is readonly. you cannot download the file if your file system is read-only